# Windows 10 partition disappeared after resizing

Tags: mac, hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

My Windows partition disappeared after resizing it. I found a post on [NERDr](http://nerdr.com/bootcamp-partition-lost-repairing-mac-partitions/) with a walkthrough for how to fix it and I did everything. This is what I got in my terminal:

```
Enter an MBR hex code (default AF): 07
Set the bootable flag? (Y/N): y

Unused partition space(s) found. Use one to protect more partitions? (Y/N): n

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): o

Disk size is 490234752 sectors (233.8 GiB)
MBR disk identifier: 0x0566FE4C
MBR partitions:

Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status      Code
   1                     1    133448879   primary     0xEE
   2      *      133448880    489972567   primary     0x07

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/disk0.
Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
partition table automatically reloaded!
Unable to open device '/dev/disk0' for writing! Errno is 1! Aborting write!

Recovery/transformation command (? for help):
```

The problem is the second to last line, says the action was aborted because the disk cannot be opened.

---

Some partition map details:

```
Andrews-MBP:~ Drew$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
Disk: /dev/disk0 geometry: 30515/255/63 [490234752 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
#: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -  490234751] <Unknown ID>
2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused     
3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused     
4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused     
Andrews-MBP:~ Drew$ sudo gpt -vv -r show /dev/disk0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=251000193024; sectorsize=512; blocks=490234752
gpt show: /dev/disk0: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Sec GPT at sector 490234751
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6        
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  131769704      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  132179344    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  133448880  356523688      4  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  489972568     262151        
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
```

---

I also have some replies in [Official Apple Support Forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7939074), but in a hurry to fix this so I also posted it here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57920/discussion-on-question-by-mrblargg-windows-10-partition-disappeared-after-resizi).

Answer (score 1):

The 4th partition got the wrong partition type. It's marked as an HFS+ partition, it should be Microsoft Basic Data though.

- Boot to Internet Recovery Mode
- Open Terminal in the menubar > Utilities > Terminal
- Enter `diskutil list` and with the disk identifier of the internal disk found there: `gpt -r show diskX`. Usually it's disk0 - below I assume it's disk0. Use the disk identifier you have found in your environment in the commands below! You also have a CoreStorage volume (e.g. FileVault). Check its disk identifier also. Below I assume it's disk2. If you haven't mounted it (because you didn't unlock it - if it is encrypted), you don't have to unmount it below.
- Unmount the logical volume and then the internal disk:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk2
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  ```
- Remove the fourth partition:

  ```
  gpt remove -i 4 /dev/disk0
  ```
- Re-add the 4th partition with the same first block and size but with the proper type:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk2
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  gpt add -b 133448880 -i 4 -s 356523688 -t EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 /dev/disk0
  ```
- Reboot

Comment: Whenever I enter gpt remove -i 4/dev/disk0 it says that the path does not exist, same result when I try to add it as well. No idea how the hell it does not exist since the terminal shows its as a result.

Comment: @MrBlargg There has to be a space between 4 and /dev/d...

Comment: Yeah I typed it properly into the console. I had a similar issue with the first solution I tried. After talking to someone else they told me theres little chance of recovery because I reformatted the partition on accident. So Im just doing a new windows version through bootcamp. Should be able to get most of my files back through professors so thatll be ok.